# Assigning memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to assign memory por double *r[3]

Whenever I try this way it keep failing:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    int N = 10;
    double *r[3] = new double[N][3];
    delete r;
    return 0;
}
```

How is the correct way?

Comment: A new expression cannot have more than one dimension.

Comment: The *correct* way is probably to use `std::vector` than naked C-style arrays.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292962/how-to-go-from-foo-pfood-to-foo-pbarrowscols/36293330#36293330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
double (*r)[3] = new double[N][3];
```

and

```
delete [] r;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign blocks of memory to each cell your pointer points to.

```
double **r = new double* [N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    *(r + i) = new double[3];

    delete [] *(r + i);
}

delete [] r;
```

Better is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::array`

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    typedef std::array<double,3> darray;
    darray *r = new darray[N];
    delete []r;
    return 0;
}
```